# IP rotation is not happening

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, axios, proxy

I'm using IPRoyal to scrap the same website with IP rotation for every request.
I get the same IP address every iteration until I restart the app. Only then the ip gets changed.

```
    const axiosInstance =
  process.env.PROXY_PROTOCOL &&
  process.env.PROXY_HOST &&
  process.env.PROXY_PORT &&
  process.env.PROXY_USERNAME &&
  process.env.PROXY_PASSWORD ?
  axios.create({
    ...(process.env.PROXY_ENABLED === 'true' ?
      {
        proxy: {
          protocol: process.env.PROXY_PROTOCOL,
          host: process.env.PROXY_HOST,
          port: Number(process.env.PROXY_PORT),
          auth: {
            username: process.env.PROXY_USERNAME,
            password: process.env.PROXY_PASSWORD
          }
        }
      } :
      {}),
    headers: {
      accept: '*/*',
      'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
      'sec-ch-ua': '"Not_A Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="120", "Google Chrome";v="120"',
      'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
      'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
      'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
      'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
      'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
      'Referrer-Policy': 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin',
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
      cookie: USD_EN_US_COOKIE
    }
  }) :
  null;

// Get ip address
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  const ipResponse: AxiosResponse = await axiosInstance.get('https://api.ipify.org');
  if (!ipResponse || ipResponse.status !== 200 || !ipResponse.data) {
    throw new Error('No response from ipify');
  }

  const ip = ipResponse.data;
  if (!ip || !ip.length) {
    throw new Error('No ip address');
  }

  console.log('ip address', ip);
}
```

I get:

```
ip address x.x.x.x
ip address x.x.x.x
ip address x.x.x.x
ip address x.x.x.x
```

instead of a random IP address every iteration.

Comment: what makes you think the IP address from IPRoyal would change for every request? I see in their documentation the phrase *"Use your dashboard or a simple API request to change your IP at any time."* - you don't seem to be using any such API - or there's *"It’s easy to auto-rotate IPs automatically every 1, 10, or 30 minutes."* ... did you wait a minute? That's the thing with using "ethically sourced IP's" for less than ethical reasons